Powering a microcontroller with an Li-ion Battery --> How to choose a protection?
The introduction
I'm currently working on a low power project that is using the ESP32-S3 microcontroller variant from Seeed Studio, the XIAO Series ESP32-S3 (Official wiki: https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/xiao_esp32s3_getting_started/). The aim of the project is to use the microcontroller to receive an image through Wi-Fi, convert it to a bitmap and display it on a e-paper display, then go into a deep-sleep state, where the whole system uses about 13-14 μA. The whole system would be "fully" on only for about 8-10 minutes a day, as the new picture would be coming only a few times a day. The other 23 hours and 50 - 52 minutes, the system would be in a deep sleep mode.
I am fairly new to powering microcontrollers with anything other than the USB port and my limited knowledge of electronics, in this field, is making me very unsure of my decisions. That is why I'm deciding to ask a question here (my first one yet).
The Problem
The XIAO ESP32-S3 has a built-in battery + and - connections and it features a voltage regulator and a battery charger integrated in the design of the board. So that part of the problem is already solved from the manufacturer. What I am to do is just simply power it with a 3.7V Li-ion battery, with a high capacitance of around 5000 mAh. The goal is that the final module can last around 6 months with a single battery charge. 
I have already looked at a few Battery Management Systems for Li-ion batteries, and they feature everything that I need: undervoltage protection, overvoltage protection, overcurrent protection (some) and short circuit protection. 
The only problem is:  they have way to low values for the undervoltage protection (~2.5V). I have tested the board with a power supply and the working area of the board with the power consumption of my whole system, lies between 3.2V and 4.2V. If the battery is not able to emit 3.2V, I need the BMS to cut the power to the system, as running the system with under 3.2V poses a risk to the components of my system. The system (whole projects with a e-paper display, few buttons, and a PMOS transistor for enabling the boost converter for bigger display that need 5V to operate). The overvoltage protection is around 4.2V so that is not a problem. The undervoltage protection is the problem.
The "Solution"
I found a few interesting videos about the topic, like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JOhQ3nsR7xo, which mentions a eFuse, this one to be specific (datasheet): 
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2596.pdf?ts=1716050939737&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Feu.mouser.com%252F 
This is a almost a perfect solution, the only problem is that the quiescent current (working current) lies between 206 and 266 µA, which is 20 times more than what my system uses in deep sleep mode, making it not a valid solution for me.
The Question
What I am really asking is, does anybody know a way how to achieve that what I described?
Could I like modify a BMS for Li-ion battery for example this one (sorry the page is in german, as the store is located in Germany): https://bikebattery.de/1S-6A-BMS-37V-18650-21700-26650-Lithium-Batterie-Ladung-Schutz-Bord-PCB-1-Stueck) with this battery: https://bikebattery.de/Samsung-INR21700-50E-36V-5000mAh-10A-Li-Ion-Akku-21700-50E to protect my system in a way that it allows the battery to power the system only in the specific area between 3.2V and 4.2V, with the 3.7V being the desired voltage? 
Or should I look in a different direction and try to solve this through software? I mean I can read the voltage of the battery with a simple voltage divider as shown in the Picture 1? 
In any case I am open to suggestions and will be active here to try to explain in more detail if needed. 
I hope I've explained my problem very clearly and would like to say thanks in advance!! :) 

I think the first problem is to power a 3.3V device directly from 4.2V downto 2.7V lithium ion battery; generally you would use a buck-boost regulator between battery and 3.3V electronics. Secondly, BMS is a safety feature, it will cut off the battery before there is too much damage to the battery. If you want to cut off at 3.2V or 2.7V, you need to hande that separately as it if is a normal condition to be in, not an emergency like 2.5V.

The XIAO board is made to be powered directly with a battery, as it has an internal step down converter that tunes it down to 3.3V, as you can see in schematics from the official wiki. Regarding the second part of your comment, I know that it's just a safety feature, I'm just looking into options that cut off the power to the board if the battery delivers less than 3.2V. But thank you for answering in such a short time!
